# x:Key is ignored inside MergedDictionaries

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two styles. One with implicit key (set via `TargetType` property), and one with explicit key:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">

            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">

            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Everything works is expected. Now, If I have the same styles defined inside `MergedDictionaries`, like that:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">

                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">

                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I get a runtime exception, stating that I have duplicate keys:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '14' and line position '19'. ---> System.ArgumentException: **Item has already been added**. Key in dictionary: 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'  Key being added: 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'

That makes no sense. Looks like `x:Key` is being ignored inside `MergedDictionaries`. Why?

Comment: Did you clean & build the solution while doing this? you can give it a try

Comment: Are you saying you tried my code (listing no. 2) and it works for you?

Comment: Setting the TargetType property to the Button type without setting an
x:Key implicitly sets the x:Key to {x:Type Button}. I assume when you add targetType for the style it doesnt check for the key.hence you got same keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in XAML. If I move `x:Key` to be the first attribute (before `TargetType`), then suddenly everything just works.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">

                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">

                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Edit:** [bug on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1799848/)